I try to install fbprophet at "(MrinmoyEnv) C:\Users\Admin\MrinmoyEnv\MrinmoyEnv>" with pip install. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
I use Windows11Home. I am trying ton install in the path "(MrinmoyEnv) C:\Users\Admin\MrinmoyEnv\MrinmoyEnv>"
it shows :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fbprophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-     based projects
numpy is already installed. How to solve this issue and install fbprophet successfully
I tried to install fbprophet in the virtual env. But it just shows this issue. Then I tried to install numpy. But because it is already installed, it shows the specific message.

Please try installing using:
pip install prophet

it will fix your problem as the fbprophet changed to prophet recently
